# Angular + Jquery Datatable responsivness not working

Tags: angular, datatables

I am using the following extension https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started

To make my jquery datatable responsive. In my angular.json file  Ihave added the following lines.

```
        "styles": [
          "node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
          "node_modules/material-icons/css/material-icons.css",
          "node_modules/datatables.net-colreorder-dt/css/colReorder.dataTables.css",
          "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
          "node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js",
          "node_modules/datatables.net-colreorder/js/dataTables.colReorder.js"
        ]
```

I then have imported DataTableModule in my app.module

```
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    DataTablesModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot(),
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: httpTranslateLoader,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule
  ],
```

I then have then created the following table here is the html of that table

```
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="display table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive row-border hover" *ngIf="employees">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>{{ 'employee.Number' | translate }} </th>
      <th>{{'employee.UserName' | translate}}</th>
      <th>
        <span class="material-icons" (click)="addEmployee()" href="javascript:void(0);">
          add_box
        </span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let employee of employees">
      <td>{{ employee.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ employee.userName }}</td>
      <td>
        <a [title]="employee.id + ' employee-details'" [routerLink]="['/employees', employee.id]">
          <span class="material-icons md-18">
            edit
          </span>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And here is the typescript file of the table.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Employee } from '../models/Employee';
import { UserService } from '../services/employee.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employees',
  templateUrl: './employees.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employees.component.css']
})
export class EmployeesComponent implements OnInit {
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
  public employees: Employee[];

  constructor(private employeeService: UserService ,private http: HttpClient) { }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 10,
      processing: true,
      responsive: true,
      columnDefs: [{
        targets: [6],
        orderable: false,
        width: "50px"
      }]
    };
    this.employeeService.getEmployees().subscribe(result => {
      this.employees = result;
    }, error => {
      console.log(error)
    });
  }

}
```

Sadly it does not work any help would be very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: @danday74 I do no see any error in the terminal nor in the visual studio 2019 console. But I do not see the green circle in my jquery data table with the plus when screen is smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please visit the [Download Page](https://datatables.net/download/index), and make sure to select **everything** that you plan on using in DataTable. In your angular.json file, I can tell you are missing two files necessary to actually enable the `responsive: true,` option.

You have not included the JS script and CSS stylesheet for the DataTables responsive option.

Here are the links to download the script and stylesheet:
https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.9/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css
https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.9/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js

Download those and be sure to reference them correctly in your Angular.json file.

i.e.

```
        "styles": [
          "node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
          "node_modules/material-icons/css/material-icons.css",
          "node_modules/datatables.net-colreorder-dt/css/colReorder.dataTables.css",
          "node_modules/datatables.net-responsive-dt/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css",
          "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
          "node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js",
          "node_modules/datatables.net-colreorder/js/dataTables.colReorder.js",
          "node_modules/datatables.net-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"
        ]
```

Comment: Thank you. Thank you it works. But I do not understand why my refrence in index.html <script src="source to responsive.min.js"></script> does not work but it works when added in index.html. Could you explain the difference Please.

Comment: @JuniorCortenbach Sorry for the late response, but Angular has it's own way to initialize your global css/js source files. This is by adding them to the `styles` and `scripts` arrays located in your `angular.json`. If you want to add in the `head` tag of your index.html, you must link it to the correct node module. i.e `<script src="node_modules/datatables.net-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>`

Comment: If my answer helped, please don't forget to award the bounty :)